# Run a command after the docker container has started running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Trying to run `sendmailconfig` after my PHP FPM (7.1-fpm) docker has started, but i'm having a hard time doing so without getting in the way of the FPM part of the container.

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install
CMD "/usr/local/bin/config.sh" && /bin/bash
```

I've tried making a script that purely executes `yes | sendmailconfig` but seems to stop the image's default script from running which causes PHP-FPM to never actually run.

The reason I want this done in the image is because I have to run the sendmailconfig command every time I restart the container, which is impractical when managing multiple docker stacks.

Comment: set php as entry point and sendmail as a command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your entrypoint to run a file you've copied in, that file should have something like the following in it

```
/usr/local/bin/config.sh

# If this isn't the correct command for you to start php-fpm look up the correct one for your image
sudo service php7.1-fpm start

# Execute the CMD passed in from the dockerfile
sudo -H bash -c "$@;"
# You'll probably be ok with just `bash -c "$@;"` if you don't have sudo installed
```